# Inputting DIV classes and ID's on my stylesheet

Tags: html, css

**I implemented the following code on my Stylesheet:**

```
.friend {
      border:4px dashed 008000;
  }
.enemy {
      border:2px dashed 008000;
  }
.family {
      border:2px dashed 008000;
  }
#archnemesis {
      border:4px solid 008000;
  }
* {
      border:4px solid 008000;
  }
```

**I also implemented this code on my html tab:**

```
<div class="family" id="archnemesis"></div>
<div class="friend" id="archnemesis"></div>
<div class="enemy"></div>
```

For some reason the result is not showing on webpage. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: add the missing `#` to the colors and remove the duplicate id's from the DOM

Answer (score 3):

Hex colors need to be prefixed with a hash.

```
border:4px dashed #008000;
```

Also, ids should be unique, meaning you should have no more than one element with a given id.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two classes for the same qualities. If you want to go ahead and clean up your CSS, **eliminate those duplicate classes.**

Also, all hexadecimal colors need to **include a # before the id**.